# Sharepoint webpart connection breaks

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-parts

I have a `webpart` with a `gridview`, and when I select a row on the grid.
The ID of the item contained in the row is sent to another `webpart` in a connection.
The other `webpart` then displays information based on the iD.

The receiving `webpart` is using a multiview to view different types of info.
What induces the error or malfunction is a `linkbutton` in one of the views in the multiview.

I have a form with a textbox, a button that says save, a `linkbutton` that says cancel (all it does is throws in a default value to the textbox and switches the `viewindex` back to the general info about the item.

For some reason, the `linkbutton` when pressed, kills my connection between the `webparts`.
And even selecting rows in the `gridview` won't solve the problem.

That was the most serious problem I have, also I have a problem where the receiving `webpart` is like one step behind just for one click, then it "gets up to speed".

Did anyone run into something similar before?

Comment: Sharepoint FREAKS ME OUT!
The reason the connection broke was that when i clicked the reset linkbutton, it put in a default value into the textbox. (it is created outside the methods and then initialized inside the CreateChildControls.. 
That was kinda wierd.. Dont you think?

Comment: It seems that the connection automaticly breaks after a postback, thats fine, i keep the itemID inside viewstate.
But what is not fine is that it wont let me update the itemID, the connection wont open again..

Comment: Caused by a textbox inside the active multiview view.. Wierd..